# How to properly sort Tasks having multi-level Task Id like 1, 1.1, 1.1.5, 1.2, 2, 2.1.3, 2.2, 4, 11, 13, 44 etc. in Project Entry screen (PM301000)?

Tags: c#, acumatica, acumatica-kb

Default Out-of-box Sorting:

[image]

Expected Sorting:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `Edit Mask` to `Unicode` for Project Task Segmented Key (CS202000) in order to allow multi-level Task CD (allowing `.` in value)

[image]

To get the expected sorting,

We will create custom BQL function which will pad the numeric portion to the out-of-box TaskCD field.

```cs
public class HierarchySorting<StringField> : BqlFormulaEvaluator<StringField>, IBqlOperand
        where StringField : IBqlField
{
    public override object Evaluate(PXCache cache, object item, 
                                    Dictionary<Type, object> pars)
    {
        PXFieldState fState = cache.GetStateExt<StringField>(item) as PXFieldState;
        return GetSortOrderValueExt(Convert.ToString(fState.Value));
    }

    public string GetSortOrderValueExt(string taskCD)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(taskCD, "[0-9]+", MatchReplacer => MatchReplacer.Value.PadLeft(10, '0'));
    }
}
```

This custom BQL function will pad zeros for any number in out-of-box TaskCD value.

[image]

We will create a new un-bound user defined field in DAC Extension of `PMTask` and will decorate with `PXFormula` having custom BQL function

```cs
public class PMTaskPXExt : PXCacheExtension<PMTask>
{
    public abstract class usrSortingTaskCD : IBqlField { }

    [PXString(IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Usr Task")]
    [PXFormula(typeof(HierarchySorting<PMTask.taskCD>))]
    public virtual string UsrSortingTaskCD { get; set; }
}
```

We will replace the sorting for the data view using the `OrderByNew` method of `PXSelectBase/PXView`.

```cs
public class ProjectEntryPXDemoExt : PXGraphExtension<ProjectEntry>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        Base.Tasks.OrderByNew<OrderBy<Asc<PMTaskPXExt.usrSortingTaskCD>>>();
    }
}
```