# Can I set a variable based on detail records in an Acumatica Report and use it to determine whether to print a detail field?

Tags: acumatica

I have an Acumatica report that creates labels for kit assemblies. The report includes the header as well as custom object detail records attached to the kit asm item.  The detail records for a given item could be the same ID or different.

I'm attempting to display or not display a field from my detail records depending on whether all the detail records for this kit asm item have the same ID.

I'm thinking I need to calculate this, store it on the kit asm header and use it to determine whether to display my field, but is there a way to do this calculation entirely within the report without additional code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm attempting to display or not display a field from my detail records depending on whether all the detail records for this kit asm item have the same ID.

If I understand correctly the report designer won't be able to do this. The limitation is that report designers treat each detail record individually and can't look at the next records. You could look at previous records by caching their value in variables as you go but can't know the value of the next detail records to be processed. Also you can't set value on previous records at the end because they are processed individually.

> I'm thinking I need to calculate this, store it on the kit asm header and use it to determine whether to display my field, but is there a way to do this calculation entirely within the report without additional code?

To compute the condition you will need to issue SQL select somehow. So it has to be done in code or through the report editor table schema. It sounds difficult to shoehorn such a condition in the table schema. I think the easiest way would be to use a [Reports User Defined Function (UDF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51728097/how-to-call-acumatica-function-from-report-designer) but they aren't easily maintainable. Having a custom field as you suggest might very well be the best solution. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51737191/7376238) on the same page recommends that instead of UDF for better maintainability.