# How to storing a file on Bin folder of Acumatica website

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I found interesting solution for Report UDF, but it does not work for saas.

[How to call Acumatica function from Report Designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51728097/how-to-call-acumatica-function-from-report-designer?answertab=active#tab-top)

Is there any step to place the ReportLauncher.aspx.cs in the Bin folder of Acumatica website?

appreciate any comments

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It will be a kind of weird approach, but yes it's possible. You'll just need on your local computer to place that file in the bin folder. Then over dialog of Customizations package navigate to Files section, and add there ReportLauncher.aspx.cs to your customization package. Yet one more time, want to say that it is kind of strange approach.